# Touched By Controversy

Tags: word-meaning, figurative-language

I have a question about the meaning of the verb "*touch*" [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-32993911):

> This year, the candlelight vigil in Hong Kong has been ***touched*** by controversy.

Definition 6b for "*touch*" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/touch) reads:

> to affect the feelings of (someone) : to cause (someone) to feel an emotion (such as sympathy or gratitude)

Does that mean that the example sentence means controversy made the vigil more emotional?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "[touch](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/touch_1)" means the following:

> 5. to have an effect on someone or something, especially by changing or influencing them:
>
>    - He has touched the lives of many people.
>    - Unemployment remains an evil that touches the whole community.
>    - **He was often touched by doubt (=doubt affected him).**

So, what it's saying is that some controversy changed or effected the candlelight vigil from its usual. Presumably the following or proceeding sentences explained how.

It does not mean it was more emotional... in fact, the phrase can be used with "emotion":

> "Never thought I'd be *touched by emotion* at Steven Gerrard's last game at Anfield but I truly am"

From [Twitter](https://twitter.com/kamranabbasi/status/599614699492286465).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you nailed it.

It means '[affect emotionally](http://%09touch%20-%20affect%20emotionallytouch%20-%20affect%20emotionally;)'.

So, the controversy did exactly what you thought. Taking this meaning in mind, reading [that news on BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-32993911) will clarify the matter.